Is it sufficient to assume a constant coherent error?
I've recently started working with quantum errors and noise and came across an intriguing but simple question. When we consider coherent errors in quantum gate operations, it's common to model them as over or underrotations. This makes sense as these errors represent systematic deviations from the ideal gate operation.
In much of the literature and practical examples, these errors are often quantified around a few degrees, a value that effectively captures the noise characteristics, as demonstrated, for instance with 3 degrees, in the qiskit lecture. However, determining such a precise error value doesn't seem straightforward. Is it truly feasible to pinpoint this value with such accuracy? Couldn't we potentially mitigate these errors by compensating for the missing rotation percentage? In my understanding it would make more sense to work with an interval of possible deviation.
I'm keen to understand how precisely these errors can be characterized and described. Any recommended literature or insights into this topic would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance :)
